# wagtailcore owner alter field migration being generated when doing app makemigrations

Tags: wagtail

When running makemigrations for other apps in this particular project I sporadically get the following wagtailcore migration being created (e.g. in this case wagtail/wagtailcore/migrations/0033_auto_20170210_0710.py) and my app migrations setting it as a dependancy. I've tried to track down the reason several times but failed and resorted to just deleting it and updating the dependancy in my app migration. I'd be grateful if anyone can point out why/where/how/what I'm doing wrong/missing here.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.10.5 on 2017-02-10 07:10
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('wagtailcore', '0032_add_bulk_delete_page_permission'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='page',
            name='owner',
            field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, related_name='owned_pages', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='owner'),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: This migration appears to be dropping the `editable=False` flag from the field. Do you have some code inside your project that monkey-patches this to make the owner field editable, by any chance?

Comment: @gasman sorry for the slow response, computer was being serviced. Thanks to your help a search for "editable = True" found that the likely culprit is this line in Puput:

     EntryPage._meta.get_field('owner').editable = True

https://github.com/APSL/puput/blob/master/puput/models.py#L204

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't a Wagtail issue. It was a Puput issue fixed in the version 0.9. Please try to update to that version.